# How to approve individual files in a pull request on Github?

Tags: github

Is there an easy way to mark files as approved, reviewed? This is especially needed when PR is big and multiple people can review parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The closest you can get is the `CODEOWNER` function: https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners